# jQuery jTable ListAction Parameter values not changing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable

I have 2 jQuery UI datepickers, and am displaying my data with jQuery jTable.
When I click the LOAD button, it calls my LoadTable function which calls my ASP.NET MVC 4 controller method with the selected dates.

First time I select dates which intentionally don't return data, but the second time when I do select correct dates, the first time's date values are always the same in my controller, so the values never change after the first selections.

Please can someone explain why this happens, or suggest a fix?
I thought it could be a jQuery AJAX callback which is not resolved, but I am not sure.

```
<div>
    <input type="datetime" id="StartDate" readonly="readonly" />
    <input type="datetime" id="EndDate" readonly="readonly" />
    <button type="button" id="btnLoadTable">LOAD</button>
</div>

<div id="JTableContainer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnLoadTable').click(function () {
        LoadTable($('#StartDate').val(), $('#EndDate').val());
    });
</script>

function LoadTable(startDate, endDate) {
    $("#JTableContainer").jtable({
    title: '',
    paging: false,
    sorting: true,
    defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
    columnSelectable: false,
    openChildAsAccordion: true,
    actions: {
        listAction: '@Url.Action("DataList")?startDate=' + startDate + '&endDate=' + endDate
    },
    fields: {
      // abbreviated for space

public JsonResult DataList(string startDate, string endDate)
{
    try
    {
        // I know a straight-parse is not best practice.
        var data = _repository.GetData(DateTime.Parse(startDate), DateTime.Parse(endDate));

        return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = data, TotalRecordCount = data.Count });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {             
        return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call $('#JTableContainer').jtable('load') to actually load the records into your table. See [jTable.org API Reference](http://jtable.org/ApiReference)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element').jtable({ajaxSettings: { type: 'GET', cache:false }});
$element.jtable('destroy');
$element.jtable({FULL JSON LOAD DATA });
$element.jtable("load");
```

[Github #issue](https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/issues/716)